# How to remove all strings inside a string AND the matching string

Tags: c#, regex

If there's already a question for this I'll delete it, but couldn't find anything quite like the issue I have. I have a string, let's say

`<blockquote> string here string here string here </blockquote>`

(usually would be a bit more complicated, but for ease of example, this is valid. I want to remove everything inside the `<blockquote> </blockquote>`, which I did quite successfully using this regex:

```
new Regex("(\\<blockquote)(.*?)(\\</blockquote\\>)");
string Result = x.Replace(Text, "$1" + repl + "$3");
```

This gets me about 90% of the way. I would like my Regex to not only remove what's in it, but also the blockquotes themselves.

[Here's](http://rextester.com/GBTP45341) a test environment which has what I currently have. I have an example string in there, that looks like this:

```
Testing: h<sub>2</sub>0 40<sup>th</sup>.<br /> <br /> <div> <blockquote class=\"twitter-tweet\" data-lang=\"en\"><p lang=\"en\" dir=\"ltr\">Breaking: Thad Matta is out as Ohio State men&#39;s basketball coach after 13 seasons. <a href=\"{link_ommitted}\">pic.twitter.com/XhFreY9j2S</a></p>&mdash; SportsCenter (@SportsCenter) <a href=\"https://twitter.com/SportsCenter/status/871793341435965441\">June 5, 2017</a></blockquote>
```

The result looks like this:

`Testing: h<sub>2</sub>0 40<sup>th</sup>.<br /> <br /> <div> <blockquote</blockquote><br /> <br /> <blockquote</blockquote> </div>`

Which like I said, gets me about 90% of the way. Now I can easily just do `Result = Result.Replace("<blockquote</blockquote>", string.Empty)` and I'd be set to go. But I wanted to know if there was a way I can do this in my initial `Regex.Replace` method as shown above.

Comment: You should use an HTML parser.

Comment: Try removing all paranthesis excep the outer ones, that should replace the whole matched string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're readding group 1 and 3 in your replace-method. Try this instead

```
string Result = x.Replace(Text, repl);
```